# Hide parent element before DOM loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, owl-carousel

Hi I'm trying to make an slide-show to work on my Wordpress theme. The theme uses broken owl carousel 2 slider, so I choose to replace it with [unslider](http://unslider.com/) which works fine, except that the slider `div`s are shown  massively above each other before page is fully loaded.

I tried to hide slider block until page fully loaded but my code didn't work .

**CSS**

```
<style  type="text/css">
  #myslideri{ visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadF() {
  document.getElementByID('myslideri').style.visibility='visible';     
} 
</script>
```

**Markup**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="loadF() ">
...
</body>
```

The theme uses bootstrap JS CSS framework and Owl Carousel 2. Even I tried to hide another div but `onload` function didn't work either with `display="none"`

Here is the full list of CSS & JS files loaded with the theme:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://wp.example.com/wp-json/' />
.....
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/js/app.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.3.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/plugins/bootstrap-for-contact-form-7/assets/scripts.min.js?ver=1.3.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/FlexSlider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/mixitup/src/jquery.mixitup.js?ver=20141212'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wp.example.com/wp-content/themes/new-theme/assets/libs/scrollreveal/dist/scrollReveal.js?ver=20141212'></script>
```

Comment: Is `myslideri` the actual id of the element?  Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: Its `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Comment: Yest I use getElementByID but I make typo her not on my script . @mariocatch I'll post my full HTML .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. That is the problem.

Comment: thanks that was the problem looks I worked long time fixing previous slide so I forgot basic attributes syntax .

Comment: @SalemF you should use a good IDE that allows code completion to avoid these kind of issues. I personally use Aptana Studio, watch this: https://github.com/JockiHendry/aptanastudio-contentassist-patch

Comment: OK that's the problem with JS it's case sensitive in weired way how can remember it's only `I` capital  without `D`

Comment: That is called CamelCase notation. Google for it to know more